# Atom Prettier + Eslint

Tags: javascript, atom-editor, text-editor, eslint, prettier

I am using prettier with eslint which works great for everything except method chaining. It breaks it in random times. I don't like how it works and would like to totally disable this feature if possible. Here is an example of what it does. I don't like how pgDB is in it's own line.

```
.map(make => {
    pgDB
        .none(
            'INSERT INTO makes(ed_id, name, nice_name) VALUES($1,$2,$3)',
            [make.ed_id, make.name, make.nice_name]
            )
```

It doesn't matter if the length of the text is long or short. 
I tried the following two rules and it seems to have no impact. I am using Atom's linter-eslint 8.21 and prettier-atom 0.351

`"newline-per-chained-call": [2, { "ignoreChainWithDepth": 10 }]
"newline-per-chained-call": [0, { "ignoreChainWithDepth": 4 }]`

Comment: I'm having the same issue. I have my prettier-atom set to pick up rules from my .eslintrc file - which works fine for all rules except this one which I'm trying to turn off. I've tried "newline-per-chained-call": "off" as well, to no avail.

Comment: I was able to fix it by going to settings -> editor and increasing the preferred-line-width option. Hope it works for you.

Comment: could you please point how to configure the whole thing, project dependencies + atom dependiencies, default eslintrc.. I'm looking for standard React/JSX style but atom just gets crazy.....  thanks